# Multiple Name Servers on one Domain

Tags: dns, nameserver

Is it possible to have two sets of nameservers for one domain... e.g.

- ns-1382.awsdns-44.org needed for site running of AWS and
- NS29.DOMAINCONTROL.COMNS30.DOMAINCONTROL.COM 
  required by another site hosted elsewhere but requires the latter (two) to resolve?

I've tried entering both and the DNS for both sites won't resolve. How can someone go about such a situation?

Comment: Hi RichLM, could you try clarifying your question, it is difficult to understand.  To answer the apparent question, "yes you can have multiple name servers for a domain, and in fact you should have two at least"

Comment: It is very difficult to discern your intent and help you based on the information you have provided.  You might want to describe the problem more accurately, and maybe we can help you solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Paul. I think my original post was actually edited. My question is - is it possible to have two different sets of name servers eg. ns31.domaincontrol.com, ns-1730.awsdns-24.co.uk,ns-89.awsdns-11.com, ns-1382.awsdns-44.org and NS29.DOMAINCONTROL.COM,NS30.DOMAINCONTROL.COM all setup under one domain. I have a number of applications running on AWS that require the AWS nameservers to resolve..and I also have another website that requires the second nameservers to resolve. From experience so far, when I have the two sets - trying to load my sites won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to discern what you are asking -

If you are asking "Can I have 2 different sets of nameservers, with different information described in them for the same resources, where the wider Internet can access both of them simultaneously" - which appears to be your question - the answer is no.

It is possible to sub-delegate, ie have the nameservers for, for example, example.com point to one set of nameservers, then to subdelegate www.example.com to another set of nameservers.

Comment: Hi David. I think my original post was actually edited. My question is - is it possible to have two different SETS of name servers in one domain eg. ns31.domaincontrol.com, ns-1730.awsdns-24.co.uk,ns-89.awsdns-11.com, ns-1382.awsdns-44.org and NS29.DOMAINCONTROL.COM,NS30.DOMAINCONTROL.COM all setup under one domain. I have a number of applications running on AWS that require the AWS nameservers to resolve..and I also have another website that requires the second nameservers to resolve. From experience so far, when I have the two sets - trying to load my sites won't work.

Comment: I know your post was edited - I edited it try and make a bit more sense of it, and believe I left the intention in tact.   I believe the answer to your question, as asked,  is "NO"  (There are a whole lot of minutia which means that yes, its technically possible, but based on the information hinted at but not stated, none of these minutia apply).   What you have not done is advised WHY you need to use 2 sets of nameservers, and what subdomains you need set up.